# Asp.Net MVC Razor Dropdown - Accessing list from ViewModel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'd like to make a dropdown menu in a cshtml file using Razor. I'm using a ViewModel, in which I define a list. I'd like to use that list's values as dropdown options. For this, I'mtrying:

```
@model GuestViewModel
...
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedLocation, m => m.travellocations, "Select location!")
```

However, for the `m => m.travellocations` (`travellocations` is a list: `travellocations = new List<SelectListItem>();`), it just says it cannot convert the lambda to a list. How can I access this list in such a dropdown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second parameter is not a lambda expression, so use this declaration:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedLocation, Model.travellocations, "Select location!")
```

The lambda expression "m" is a shortcut for Model anyway.

Comment: Oh thanks, I knew all that stuff except for that I can actually use Model by default :)